# Is it possible to have emacs-live and vanilla emacs live together?

Tags: emacs

I'd like to have emacs-live as a *second* emacs (the first one being the vanilla version heavily personalized) that can conexist with another installation.

I guess the binary will always be the same but what is the easiest way to make it start as emacs-live instead of reading the usual preferences?

*UPDATE*: I'm using mac os x Lion (but I guess this answer is os independent)

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Answer (score 1):

you could make another user, say, live, and install emacs-live into it. then you could run

```
emacs -u live
```

take a look [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)